# Can the transfer of numerous small files damage an external hdd?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure

my (rather new) external HDD (Seagate Expansion Portable) is slowly dying. It was used for backups of simulation results, that were written in thousands of small text files. Filesize was between 40kB and 3MB. I'm estimating that overall about 3GB-6GB were written/deleted twice a day, 4 times a week. This was done over the course of the last 6 months. Other than that, the HDD wasn't used much, mostly just plugged in during the day. The backups were somewhat slow (grsync was used in linux), but this was to be expected as many small files were transferred.

Is it possible that the specific scenario led to an early death?

Thank you!

Comment: HDDs are designed to have files of all files transfered to it.  A mechanical HDD does not "wear out" by having data written to it.

Comment: What are the SMART test results?

Comment: @DavidPostill SMART is not available for this HDD.

Comment: With only about 70Gb being written to the drive I really doubt this was a failure caused by the use case. More likely it was just a bad hdd and should be returned under warranty.